# Chart.js v2, remove padding/margin from radar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

Has anyone run into the issue of removing padding (or margin?) from a `chartjs` chart?

Below is my code (in jsFiddle)...and image (notice the bottom? UGLY sauce).

***Here's a JSFiddle that highlights the issue. Notice the padding at the bottom of the white box.*** https://jsfiddle.net/mre1p46x/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap a bit of logic around the `fit` method using the `beforeFit` and `afterFit` handlers to correct this padding when the number of labels is 3 (the `fit` function starts off by assuming a maximum radius of half the chart height. For a triangle, we actually have a bit more space)

All we do is scale the `height` property to compensate for this assumption, like so

```
...
options: {
    scale: {
        beforeFit: function (scale) {
            if (scale.chart.config.data.labels.length === 3) {
                var pointLabelFontSize = Chart.helpers.getValueOrDefault(scale.options.pointLabels.fontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize);
                scale.height *= (2 / 1.5)
                scale.height -= pointLabelFontSize;
            }
        },
        afterFit: function (scale) {
            if (scale.chart.config.data.labels.length === 3) {
                var pointLabelFontSize = Chart.helpers.getValueOrDefault(scale.options.pointLabels.fontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize);
                scale.height += pointLabelFontSize;
                scale.height /= (2 / 1.5);
            }
        },
            ...
```

---

The scaling factor `2 / 1.5` is pretty easy to figure out

1. With `h = distance from center of triangle to a corner`
2. Total height of the triangle `= h + distance from center of triangle to a side
                            = h + h * sin 30
                            = 1.5 h`
3. h currently `= chart height / 2`
4. We want to scale this by r, such that

   `1.5 * chart height / 2 * r = chart height`
5. This gives us

   `r = 2 / 1.5`

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zqp525gf/